# Get current value URL?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying validate some values passed from a URL. I'm trying get these values in a UI but does not work.

I'm trying this.

```
// link send by email, click to validate
String url = "http://localhost:8080/MyProject/ValidateValues?NAME=FERNANDO&AGE=34"

// ValidateValues UI class
public class ValidateValues extends UI{
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        String name = request.getParameter("NAME");
        String age = request.getParameter("AGE");

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(age);
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code provides a working solution:

```
String sPathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
if ("/ValidateValues".equals(sPathInfo)) {
    // TODO: Check if NAME and AGE are contained in the ParameterMap!
    String sName = request.getParameterMap().get("NAME")[0];
    String sAge = request.getParameterMap().get("AGE")[0];
    Notification.show(String.format("Name: %s Age: %s", sName, sAge));
}
else {
    // not correct path
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work at the String level.

First get the substring that contains all the values.

```
String allVal = url.substring(url.indexOf("?"));
```

Then you can split this string using & as delimiter to get assignations.

```
String[] values = allVal.split("&");
```

To finish you can split each element of values using = as delimiter.

```
for(String val : values){
   String[] a= val.split("=");
   String varName=a[0];
   String varValue=a[1];
 }
```

You can now use varName and varValue to make your validations

Answer (score 0):

VaadinRequest doesn't provide a straightforward method for getting the whole actual URL, however using `request.getParameter("v-loc");` may solve this problem. When you have complete URL it's possible to play with it using `java.lang.String` toolkit